# Can You Make the Podcasts App Show Only Downloaded Episodes?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts.app

I've never met anyone who loves Apple's podcasts app.  But I could make peace with it if not for one infuriating design choice that I can't figure out how to correct.

I have set up iTunes to sync all unplayed podcast episodes to my iPhone.  The Podcasts app is set to not download anything itself and keep only unplayed episodes.  So, I sync an episode, listen to it on the Podcasts app, and then the file is removed from the iPhone on next sync.  But it still shows up in the list, with a little cloud icon (#521):

[image: podcasts app]

**Is there any way to prevent non-downloaded podcasts from showing up in this app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, albeit an unsatisfactory one.  The way to get the behavior I want is to uninstall the podcasts app from the mobile device, and then reinstall it during the next sync.  This resets everything to how it should be in the first place.